# getDrawingCache() in another layout

Tags: android

I have code like this:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
```

...

```
 FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.rLayout_main);

 frameLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

 frameLayout.buildDrawingCache(true);

 Bitmap bitmap = frameLayout.getDrawingCache();
```

The bitmap NOT null when id.rLayout_main in layout activity_main. 
But when I replace id.rLayout_main to id.layout_report, it's not in layout activity_main, it's in layout report. I change code like this:

```
 FrameLayout viewGroup= new FrameLayout(context);

 LayoutInflater inflaters = LayoutInflater.from(context);

 View root = inflaters.inflate(R.layout.report,viewGroup, true);

 FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.layout_report);

 frameLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

 frameLayout.buildDrawingCache(true);

 Bitmap bitmap = frameLayout.getDrawingCache();
```

This time, bitmap always return NULL. Please Help Me!!!

Comment: I guess it's because this view is not layout on the screen.

Comment: Yes, I guess so, but I don't know how to draw that view. It's mean that I don't want to show the view that I going to draw in screen. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your view has been inflated but it has not been drawn yet. That is why the bitmap is null. What if you do this:

```
FrameLayout viewGroup = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.rLayout_main);
LayoutInflater inflaters = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View root = inflaters.inflate(R.layout.report,viewGroup, true);
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.layout_report);
frameLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
frameLayout.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = frameLayout.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: try moving Bitmap bitmap = frameLayout.getDrawingCache(); to onResume and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I moved those to OnResume(), but nothing difference. I moved those to onCreate(), bitmap was not NULL anymore but everything in layout_report show in screen. I'm going crazy !!!

Comment: IT shows on the screen because  of this line FrameLayout viewGroup = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.rLayout_main); if you don't want to show it then remove it from the framelayout after you got the bitmap